# Is it safe to disable the guest account in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

Tech info: OS:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , Memory: 993.1 Mib Processer intel (r) CPU T2050 (Dual Core) @ 1.6 GHZ (1600Mhz), Os:32 bit.... im using an HP Pavillion DV5220us

is it safe to disable the guest account on ubuntu using the following method:

By default ubuntu 12.04 comes with guest account.You can disable this account using the following procedure.Guest account is a paswordless account which allow users to get access to Ubuntu machine

Open /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file from your terminal using the following command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line

```
allow-guest=false
```

Save and exit the file

After adding the above line you should see similar to the following in lightdm.conf file

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
```

Finally you have to restart lightdm using the following command from your terminal

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, **Yes.**

I can't think of any side-affects possible, just the gained security of not having guest access to your system. Granted, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to internal matters of the system like this, but it would make sense that it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The guest account is just with minimal permissions and be sure its safe to keep.

There is no security issues from keeping guest account.. Also, keep in mind when it comes to security any physical contact with your PC means no security at all.

so, if you are asking about security be sure its safe to keep.

People wish to disable to forbid others from using their Pc's, thats all...